# UnsatisfiedLinkError on xawt when running HEC-HMS.sh

Tags: java, libraries

I am a recent adopter of Linux and this problem has got me stumped. I use [HEC-HMS](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-hms/downloads.aspx) and [HEC-DSSVue](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-dssvue/downloads.aspx) for work on a regular basis. I have been using the widows versions in wine but they are really buggy. So I decided to try out the linux versions. the links below will take you to the download pages for these two programs. They are free programs for Hydrology and data management.

Once I install them and attempt to run the shell file (`HEC-HMS.sh` for example) I get a ton of java errors that I do not understand. If I had to guess I would say that the java files in question can not be found. When I check to see if java is installed it is.

Here is the output from the terminal from trying to run `HEC-HMS.sh`:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/smythe/HEC/hec-hms35/java/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.DebugHelper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at hms.i.c(Unknown Source)
    at hms.i.b(Unknown Source)
    at hms.K.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/smythe/HEC/hec-hms35/java/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.CUPSPrinter.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup.getDefaultPrintService(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup.refreshServices(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup$PrinterChangeListener.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at hms.model.l.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hms.model.ProjectManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hms.Hms.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hms.Hms.main(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.print.CUPSPrinter
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup.getDefaultPrintService(Unknown Source)
    at javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(Unknown Source)
    at hms.util.f.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I get similar outputs when I try to run `HEC-DSSVue.sh`. If anyone could shed some light on a solution I would really appreciate it.

The problem turned out to be that the program needed 32 bit versions of the particular dependencies.

Comment: @Mitch How did you make the scroll box around my text? I looked for the option but obviously missed it. I want to make sure I have good dedicate on the forums whenever possible. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Just highlight the text that you want, and click on the <$> icon on top of the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a library that's required by this program.

```
/home/smythe/HEC/hec-hms35/java/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You need to install `libXtst.so.6`. A [search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for packages containing this file yields [libxtst6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libxtst6).

```
Could not initialize class sun.print.CUPSPrinter
```

I think that's part of the JDK, but it seems to require awt, which couldn't be initialized above, so once you fix the first error you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the error message.

I'm pretty certain you're missing libraries, or that they can't be read, given that this message shows up ***twice*** in the trace: `/home/smythe/HEC/hec-hms35/java/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

That suggests that one of two things is happening:

1. The library files in question are missing, and therefore unusable.
2. The library files in question exist, but do not have the correct permissions, which means Java can't actually "see" the files.

The solution depends on the situation:

1. (a)If the library files are indeed missing, then you need to place the library files into that directory.
   (b) Install the `libxtst6` package to get the libraries on your system.  If you need to include the libraries in your source for some reason, you need to download them separately and include them.
2. If the library files exist but are not readable, then you need to provide us details on ownership of those files (pasting the output of `ls -l /home/smythe/HEC/hec-hms35/java/lib/i386/xawt/` wouldn't hurt, so we can see the ownership rights on it, as well as read/write/execute permissions.)

Comment: I attempted to install the `libxtst6` package via the pat-get command and was told that it is already installed and the most recent version. I ran the `ls -l` that you asked and this was the output `smythe@thinktwice:~$ ls -l /home/smythe/HEC/hec-hms35/java/lib/i386/xawt/ 
total 348
-rwxr-xr-x 1 smythe smythe 353102 Oct 31  2010 libmawt.so`

Comment: UPDATE: I opened up synaptic and checked to make sure the libxtst6 packages were in the list and marked for instillation. All of the dependency listed in the link bellow are marked for install.      http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libxtst6

Comment: I have done some reading over the last few days and I was wondering if it is possible that these are 64 bit and both HEC-HMS and HEC-DSSVue are looking for 32 bit versions?

Comment: It might be, if it's trying to build i386 on amd64 it might be problematic, they don't have a 64bit build do they?

Comment: they do have both a 32bitand a 64 bit version. The site list them like this, Linux (32bit x86) and Solaris (64bit SPARC). I believe I tried to install the Solaris version. I had installed the Solaris version. I just installed the 32bit package now ans I get an identical error. I also notice that both error messages point to an i386 directory. I have done some looking and I can not figure out how to go about trying to get the 32bit version of these dependencies.